# Is there a module that can record when and for how long each user logs in for? (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I'm working on developing a website as part of an academic project that requires tracking individual user activity throughout a long period of time. We need to do the very minimum track when users log in and for how long (or until they timeout). I haven't been able to find a module that does this, except for [Open Web Analytics](http://piwik.org/) which is breaking some of our pages.

I'm not completely closed to the idea of rolling my own solution but I'd like to do it through a tested module if possible.

Comment: Never heard about a module with this kind of option.. and probably wont be easy to implement without affect the performance

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [User Visits Advanced](https://drupal.org/project/user_visits_adv) module, It have the option to track the hours visited by the users.

> The User Visits Advanced module is a contribute module for the User
>   Visits module. It is extremely useful for social networking sites who
>   wish to provide their users with statistics about the number of times
>   a the users profile page is being viewed and by which other users.
>
> This module comes with its own database table to store statistics per
>   user profile (uid). At cron time, the data from the user_visits table
>   is collected, aggregated and stored in the user_visits_adv table. It
>   stores
>
> - the total number of visits per uid
> - the number of visits of the X past days per uid
> - **the most recent visitors uids of the past Y hours**

Answer (score 1):

I found [this post](https://groups.drupal.org/node/161414#comment-943633) after some digging.

> You can edit the googleanalytics.admin.inc file in the module.
>   Uncomment forbidden tokens such as [uid] and [user-raw]. The forbidden
>   tokens are at the very end of that file.
>
> Once that's done you can create custom measures in your google
>   analytics account and track users.
>
> Good luck.

This requires [Google Analytics](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) obviously.

Answer (score 0):

https://drupal.org/project/autologout might have some code that you could use as a starting point for your own solution.

Some details from the module's project page:

> This module provides a site administrator the ability to log users out after a specified time of inactivity.
>   It is highly customizable and includes "site policies" by role to enforce logout.